# Trigger Parameterized jenkins job when a push event occurs on github

Tags: jenkins, github, github-api, cloudbees

We have a requirement wherein we have to trigger parameterized Jenkins job whenever a push event has occurred on github.

I created github hook for push event whose Payload URL looks like below to check if any of one could work.

1st Payload URL : 
https://JenkinsServer/job/JobName/build?parameter=value

Error :

Error 400 This page expects a form submission

---

2nd Payload URL : 
https://JenkinsServer/job/JobName/buildWithParameters?parameter=value

Error :

Error 500 An error occurred processing your request. Ask your Jenkins administrator to look up details